# Writing an array declaration string

Tags: java, generics

I am working on a tool that writes java files. At a given point I have to write an array declaration. I have implemented the following methods:

```
  public static String arrayToCode(Long[] arr, String arrName) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    sb.append("Long[]" + arrName + " = { ");
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      sb.append(arr[i] + "L, ");
    }
    sb.append("};");

    return sb.toString();
  }

  public static String arrayToCode(String[] arr, String arrName) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    sb.append("String[]" + arrName + " = { ");
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      sb.append(arr[i] + "L, ");
    }
    sb.append("};");

    return sb.toString();
  }

  public static String arrayToCode(Double[] arr, String arrName) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    sb.append("Double[]" + arrName + " = { ");
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      sb.append(arr[i] + "L, ");
    }
    sb.append("};");

    return sb.toString();
  }
```

However, I would like to make a single and generic method for all sorts of arrays, the thing is that I don't know how to handle the type with generics, i.e. how would I know it is a `Long`, `String` or `Double` array?

Comment: Why is one of the arguments an actual array instance instead of just the name of the type (as a String)? Oh, and BTW, arrays and Java generics don't mix well at all.

Comment: What is this about: `+ "L, "` (from `sb.append(arr[i] + "L, ");` in the loops)

Comment: That is to convert any integers to Long, that may pose a problem for other types though. Thanks for catching it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accept an `Object[]` and then use `getClass()` to figure out what type it really is.

```
public static String arrayToCode(Object[]  arr, String arrName) {
    String arrayTypeText = getArrayType(arr);
    sb.append(arrayTypeText + " " + arrName + ...);
    //...
}


private String getArrayType(Object[] arr) {
    Class<?> clazz = arr.getClass();
    if ( clazz == Double[].class ) {
        return "Double[]";
    } else if (...) {
    }
}
```

An alternative implementation of `getArrayType()` might be

```
private String getArrayType(Object[] arr) {
    return arr.getClass().getComponentType().getSimpleName() + "[]";
}
```

If you're really trying to generate code you probably should just use the fully qualified name, in which case you can replace `getSimpleName()` above with `getName()` (which will return `java.lang.Long`, e.g.)

Comment: specifically, getClass().getComponentType()

Answer (score 6):

```
public static String arrayToCode(Object[] arr, String arrName) {
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    sb.append(arr.getClass().getComponentType() + "[]" + arrName + " = { ");
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      sb.append(arr[i] + "L, ");
    }
    sb.append("};");

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Hmm I don't see how my post didn't say exactly this, with the exception that mine mentions to use `getName` which in this case is required as `toString` doesn't return only `getName()`.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few objects for Class - getName(), getCanonicalName().  Not sure of the difference.

```
public class CodeGen {

    public static String arrayToCode(Object[] arr, String arrName) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        sb.append(arr.getClass().getCanonicalName()+" " + arrName + " = { ");
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            sb.append(arr[i] + "L, ");
        }
        sb.append("};");

        return sb.toString();
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String[] foo = new String[] { "a","b","c" };
        System.out.println(arrayToCode(foo, "foobar"));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public class Foo
{
  public static void main(String [] args)
  {
    System.out.println(
    arrayToList(new Integer[] {1, 2 ,3}, "Foo")
    );
  }

  public static <T> String arrayToList (T[] data, String name)
  {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    sb.append(data[0].getClass().getSimpleName() + "[]" + name + " = { ");
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) 
    {
        sb.append(data[i] + "L, ");
    }
    sb.append("};");

    return sb.toString();
  }
}
```

Comment: arrayToList(new Integer[]{}, "Foo");  will throw IndexOutOfBoundsException.  Oops!